# Word VBA parse text and turn it into a table

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Input:

```
##TABLE_START##
##ROWS=3
##COLS=2
##Value
##Decode
##0
##Clock running
##1
##Clock not running
##TABLE_END##

##TABLE_START##
##ROWS=4
##COLS=2
##Value
##Decode
##0
##Off
##1
##On
##Z
##High Z
##TABLE_END##
```

Desired output:

[image: Data into tables]

I want to do this for about 400 tables. I tried recording a macro in word, but it locks the mouse when recording the macro, and it just records the absolute keys hit. I would like to do something more general that searches for `##TABLE_START##`, parses all the rows until `##TABLE_END##`, then builds a table at the bottom of the document filled in with the appropriate information.

Current Code Word VBA 2010: (Just a snippet of the code -- It just recorded the keystrokes whereas I want to make something that works for every table)

The copy and paste is good, but I need to change how the selection is made to be more general and work for every table

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=7
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=6
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=7
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Note: I'm aware this isn't a complete answer

This should get you started by searching line by line for the word "start". When found, you can start building the table. Then you can see [StackOverflow creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366136/creating-tables-in-ms-word-using-vba).

```
Sub tablemaker()
Dim dDoc As Document
Set dDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim rRng As Range
Dim p As Paragraph
   
For Each p In dDoc.Paragraphs
Set rRng = p.Range
    With rRng.Find
       .Text = "start"
        If .Execute Then
        'create table
        Set rRng = Nothing
        End If
    End With
    Next
End Sub
```